# Where should the 76139 Batmobile roof pins land?

Tags: building

[Lego Batmobile 76139](https://brickset.com/sets/76139-1/1989-Batmobile).
Could someone please advise whether the pins installed in step 445 should rest on top of or just in front of the stanchions installed in step 417 ?

Answer (score 5):

*Caveat: I don't have this set, so am just looking at the instructions.*

It looks like the pins should rest alongside the Axle 1L with Pin 3L you pushed into place on step 294:

[image: Locking Axle Pins]

You can possibly see that a bit clearer on step 447:

[image: Pin floating, not locked to anything]

They should therefore rest just in front of the two SNOT assembles you added in step 417.

That's also borne out if you count 12 studs from where the Axle and Pin connector sits when lowered - the end of the 12L axle comes to the just behind the pin mentioned in step 294.

Comment: Thank you so much - I thought I was right but just wanted confirmation before moving on :)